# Wrong redirection of Route againts the specified Controller method

Tags: php, laravel

My application keeps redirecting against my specification. I want to store a new data, but once submitted, it suppose to redirect to the list page but instead it remains in the create page while saving the data. Same thing applied to the update method.
Here is my route:

```
Route::post('add_assets', 'AssetsController@store');
```

And my Controller return statement

```
 return redirect()->route('agent/assets_list');
```

in the views I have

```
<form  method="post" action="/agent/assets_list" data-toggle="validator">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
```

Despite this, it still remains on the add_assets page but it saves the data as specified in the store method.

In the case of the Update method, this is the url I got

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets_list/1
```

with the "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: have you specified route name? I think `route()` method requires route name parammeter (usually contsins dots) such as `return redirect()->route('agent.assets_list');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try to use*

```
return redirect('agent/assets_list');
```

because you should pass name not the actual route to route function

**example**

web.php

```
Route::get('dashboard/users')->name('users-list');
```

**correct**

```
return redirect()->route('users-list');

return redirect('dashboard/users');
```

**incorrect**

```
return redirect()->route('dashboard/users');
```

and Change your form action to action="add_assets"

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked on the store method, But not on the update method